# Determining wheter HTML5 mode is enabled in a controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

In a controller in Angular Js, I want to learn if html5Mode is enabled, or not. How can I do that?

### Details:

In config phase I can set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` or I can learn html5Mode is enabled or not by using `$locationProvider.html5Mode()`

However, I can't do the same on a "run" block, like this:

```
var isHtml5enabled = $location.html5mode() // looking for something like this...
```

Is there a way to do this?

### Update

Why I need it?

I am trying to modify [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

`ui-router`'s `ui-sref` directive and `$state.href("")` service/method generates url *without considering* if it is in Html5Mode or not.

If Html5Mode is enabled, a url like this is ok: `/my/base/path/generated/by/uirouter`
But if it's disabled, it should be like this: `/my/base/path/#/generated/by/uirouter`

So I'm trying to detect status of Html5Mode.

I did it on config phase, but another module can change status of it after I read the information. (I guess...) That is why I want to determine status of Html5Mode on a controller/run block.

Answer (score 8):

Although it's late but I find that you can detect whether HTML5 mode is on by `$location.$$html5`. So you can do this in your controller:

```
if (!$location.$$html5) {
    // your code to execute when HTML5 mode is not enabled
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at [the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/location.js), it seems that you cannot check whether `html5Mode` is turned on or off from a controller by default.  You could, however, write your own service that is used in `.config` and `.controller` that would expose this information.

I have to ask though, why would your controller need to know such information?  I'm guessing that you might be doing something that is best done another way.

After looking at [the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/location.js), it seems that you cannot check whether `html5Mode` is turned on or off from a controller by default.  You could, however, write your own service that is used in `.config` and `.controller` that would expose this information.

I have to ask though, why would your controller need to know such information?  I'm guessing that you might be doing something that is best done another way.

**Update**

I suppose if you're already in `ui-router` making changes, you could go the distance and modify [location.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/location.js) and repackage Angular as well (or just edit angular.js and re-minify it yourself)?  It wouldn't take much, you'd just need to modify the `$location` object after line 512 to add a function that exposes the local `html5Mode` variable.

Comment: @UmutBenzer Updated my answer as well.